# Is it possible to script data as Insert statements from within an SSIS package?

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql-server-ce, ssis

SQL Server 2008 provides the ability to script data as Insert statements using the Generate Scripts option in Management Studio.  Is it possible to access the same functionality from within a SSIS package?

Here's what I'm trying to accomplish:

I have a scheduled job that runs nightly and scripts out all the schema and data from an SQL Server 2008 database. It then uses the script to create a `mirror copy` SQLCE 3.5 database.  I've been using *Narayana Vyas Kondreddi's* [**sp_generate_inserts**](http://vyaskn.tripod.com/code/generate_inserts.txt) stored procedure to accomplish this, but it has problems with few data types and also has issues with handling more than 4,000 columns (holdovers from SQL Server 2000 days).

The Script Data function looks like it could solve my problems, if only I could automate it.

Any suggestions?

Comment: It looked like SMO might save the day, but in the Books Online documentation for the Scripter.Script and Scripter.ScriptWithList methods it states "This method throws an exception if it is invoked when the ScriptData property is set to True. This prevents the entire dataset from being scripted to a StringCollection object." So, while you can do a lot of interesting things with SMO, the nice Script Data functionality that you get through the Management Studio is hamstrung there.

Comment: Maybe SMO will yet save the day.  You have to use the Scripter.EnumScript method instead of Scripter.Script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use my [**Export2SqlCE**](http://exportsqlce.codeplex.com) command line utility, which scripts both data and schema in SQL Compact compatible script. SMO does not support SQL Compact syntax and data type conversion.

Comment: I just tried out the Export2SqlCE utility from a command line and it works great.  I had already written code to convert SQL Server schema to SQLCE schema.  I wish I had known about this utility before I started rolling my own.

Answer (score 3):

It is possible to automate the scripting of all a table's data as Insert statements by using SMO's **`Scripter.EnumScript`** method.  Here is the code that I came up with.

```
Using conn As New SqlConnection(SqlServerConnectionString)
    Dim smoConn As New ServerConnection(conn)
    Dim smoServer As New Server(smoConn)
    Dim smoDatabase As Database = smoServer.Databases(smoConn.DatabaseName)
    Dim smoTables As SqlSmoObject() = New SqlSmoObject(2) {smoDatabase.Tables("Employee"), _
                                                           smoDatabase.Tables("Company"), _
                                                           smoDatabase.Tables("Job")}

    Dim smoScripter As New Scripter(smoServer)
    With smoScripter.Options
        .ScriptData = True
        .ScriptSchema = False
        .IncludeDatabaseContext = False
        .EnforceScriptingOptions = True
        .SchemaQualify = False
    End With

    Dim outputScript As New StringBuilder()
    For Each script As String In smoScripter.EnumScript(smoTables)
        outputScript.Append(script)
    Next

    Return outputScript.ToString()
End Using
```

A little too late to help me, I also found some other people who discussed the same challenge at the MSDN forums:

[**ScriptData doesn't script data**](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqlsmoanddmo/thread/f456a535-f7c1-49f7-90f4-6a8bf251fd3b)